# Javascript continue label inside a complete callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, animation, continue

I need to run a loop which gets every `div` inside a container, and fades each one in one by one.

By using this code, the elements fade in all at the same time.

```
$('#gifts1 .giftBubble').each(function(){
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

But I need each element to fade in once the previous has finished fading in.

I figured that I need to use the `continue` label to go to the next iteration of the loop only when the animation has completed, but this returns as an *Illegal Continue Statement*

```
$('#gifts1 .giftBubble').each(function(){
    $(this).fadeIn(function(){
        continue;
    });
});
```

How can I fade in each element one by one instead of them all fading in at the same time?

Comment: `continue` is only valid inside loops.

Comment: It *is* in a loop, it's just within the function

Comment: "`continue` is only valid inside an iteration statement, but not crossing function boundaries" Better?